# Mosquito physics

Tags: zoology, entomology

What are the environmental limitations of mosquitos I should know of if I want to avoid getting bitten?

For example:

- How fast should I walk in order to be moving too fast for one to bite
  me?
- Can a fan work to blow mosquitos away from me?
- If I'm looking to
  buy an apartment, is there a minimum height in which mosquitos will
  no longer reach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Speed of mosquitoes vary from place to place and their current health status.But if there is any such problem, maybe you can run a short distance (some yards) and then they won't harass you for some time till they cope up with you.

Yeah, a fan usually at comfortable speed will be enough to blow the mosquito away. If this doesn't work then set speed at full speed and wrap yourself in a blanket

I don't think there is some height where mosquitoes can't reach but my friend who lives on 12th floor in his apartment hardly has 4-5 mosquitoes bugging him.

Comment: Could you provide some references?

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting this web page http://spectrum.ieee.org/consumer-electronics/gadgets/backyard-star-wars which describe a prototype of a system to kill mosquitoes by means of a LASER, for what regard the speed:

> Mosquitoes fly up to a meter per second.

This speed is compatible with 1.2 meter per second quoted in the paper

[SNOW, W. F. Field estimates of the flight speed of some West African mosquitoes. *Annals of tropical medicine and parasitology*, 1980, 74.2: 239-242.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6108094)

> There was a relationship between wind speed and catches of Anopheles
>   melas and Culex thalassius which attempted to bite man at ground level
>   and at 4 and 8 m on  an open scaffolding tower, in cleared bush in The
>   Gambia. It was expected that in winds which exceeded their flight
>   speed, no mosquitoes would be able to approach  and attack men on the
>   tower. Catches of mosquitoes fell off sharply in winds of 120 cm/s,
>   which may approximate to their flight speed, although some insects
>   were still captured at the highest wind speeds encountered.

For what regard the flying altitude:

> The average flying altitude varies among mosquito species but is
>   usually only about 2 meters. They will fly over obstacles when
>   necessary—even into an upper-story window—but if your virtual fence is
>   3 to 5 meters high, it can catch almost all mosquitoes that fly by.

The system is patented and the patent is specific about *Anopheles*:

> For example, more than 99% of *Anopheles* mosquitoes (which may carry
>   strains of malaria that can infect humans) fly at less than 3-5 meters
>   of altitude

[HYDE, Roderick A., et al. *Photonic fence*. U.S. Patent Application 14/255,119, 2014.](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140226860)

Answer (score 3):

Environmental limitations of mosquitos can be:

**1) Wind. Prefer a windy day for a walk in the marches! Or a large ceiling fan above you bed makes a real barrier against mosquitoes!**
Mosquitoes cannot fly against the wind if the wind is more than ~1m/s as you read in your reference.

**1) Temperature. Prefer the winter season or AC-rooms!**
Some species hibernate during winter (but they still need to take some blood meal from time to time). If it is spring or if spring season doesnt exist where you are, prefer a cold day. It is relative to the normal temperature of the considered location. Some cold-climate species swarm very well at 12°C (Aedes communis  https://doi.org/10.1016/J.JINSPHYS.2021.104233)

**2) Humidity. Prefer the dry season or dry locations!**
Mosquitoes prefer humid places, otherwise they could die. Again, it depends of the species and some got adapted to arid location. However, they always need water to lay their eggs.

**3) Mechanical barrier. Prefer to sleep under a bednet!**
Mosquitoes are small and are very good to pass below your door in in a small holes of your window, however they cannot pass if you are in an isolate place. To keep some afresh air, use a bed net. It is a recommended by WHO (https://www.who.int/elena/titles/bednets_malaria_pregnancy/en/)